# NSDateFormatter local date format issue

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have NSDate, and I need to convert it to string.

Usually I use this code:

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
    return stringFromDate;
```

But I need to show data according to local date format. For instance, in USA the date usually starts from the month, but in Russia the date starts from day (`@"dd/MM/yyyy"`). And may be there is a different way of separators in different countries: `'/', '.' ',' '-'`

What is the best approach to do this?

**Update (according to Jon Skeet answer):**

if I specify NSDateFormatterMediumStyle the date is "4.9.2013", but for me it's better "04.09.2013". NSDateFormatterShortStyle doesn't help with this neither. Is there a way to add zeroes ?

Comment: so want to change formate of date according to different countries right?

Comment: so for that you should check condition with NSLocale and set formatter in that condition because automatic detection and conversion is not possible.

Comment: pls take a look at Jon Skeet answer

Comment: I highly recommend to have a look at [Date programming tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/dates.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the [date formatter guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) which gives advice about this, suggesting that you set the *style* rather than calling `setDateFormat`:

> `NSDateFormatter` makes it easy for you to format a date using the settings a user configured in the International preferences panel in System Preferences. The `NSDateFormatter` style constants—`NSDateFormatterNoStyle`, `NSDateFormatterShortStyle`, `NSDateFormatterMediumStyle`, `NSDateFormatterLongStyle`, and `NSDateFormatterFullStyle`—specify sets of attributes that determine how a date is displayed according to the user’s preferences.

It then gives a listing showing an example starting with this:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

It sounds like you'd want `NSDateFormatterShortStyle` instead though.

`setDateFormat` is what you use for a *custom* format. More advice from the same document:

> There are broadly speaking two situations in which you need to use custom formats:
>
> - For fixed format strings, like Internet dates.
> - For user-visible elements that don’t match any of the existing styles

Comment: yes, but if I specify NSDateFormatterMediumStyle the date is "4.9.2013", but for me it's better "04.09.2013". NSDateFormatterShortStyle doesn't help with this neither. Is there a way to add zeroes ?

Comment: @PaulGalavic: No - that's the way that the system has determined is the most appropriate one for your locale. You may be able to *fetch* that format, replace `d` with `dd` etc, and then set it back - but it'll be different to any other app that uses the prescribed way of formatting dates.